# How can I plot time series of different frequencies and scales in adjacent boxes?

Tags: r, matlab, ggplot2

I have a time series that I sample in alternating frequencies, i.e. in low frequencies (say, days) and in high frequencies (minutes). In low frequencies, the series does not exhibit wild fluctuations, whereas in high frequencies it explodes, i.e. grows exponentially.

I would like to plot this series in adjacent boxes, in a single figure. Schematically, this is what I would like to achieve, where gray areas are high-frequency sample periods in semi-log scale, and white areas are linearly scaled, low frequency sampling areas:

[image]

Is it possible to draw a time series like this in MATLAB, or in R/ggplot2? And how?

Comment: Does it even make sense to plot part of vector with a linear scale and another part with a log scale? The points at the boundaries would not line up. What about `plotyy`? Then you can overlay the linear and log scale plots.